# Getting the primary key of a ForeignKey field without querying the database again in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...

class Model2(models.Model):
    ...
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
```

Now, lets say I have an object of `Model2` with `pk=241` which is related to another object of `Model1` with `pk=102`. I am querying them as follows:

```
 model2 = Model2.objects.get(pk=241)
```

Now, if I want the `pk` of the referenced `Model1` object. I do the following:

```
 model2.model1.pk
```

This should not query the database again according to what I understand about tables, but if I run the following:

```
 from django.db import connection
 connection.queries
```

I get a list of 2 queries. Why do I need to query my database again to only get the primary key of my related object? Is there a way to avoid doing this?

**I am aware of `select_related()`, however, what if I want to call the `Model1` objects pk in the `save()` method of the `Model2` class?**

Moreover, is `select_related()` required even if I want to just retrieve the pk of the related object and nothing more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the underlying field without a db hit.

```
model2.model1_id
```

You don't need `select_related` here, since you are not actually accessing the related object.